# Is the constraint $A^2 = B^2$ convex

Tags: convex-analysis

I am trying to use a continuous constraint to replace a discrete equation $A = |B|$ in my model. Since the linear programming method for absolute value is inapplicable in my model, I come up with constraints
$$
A^2  = B^2;\\A \ge 0
$$
to enforce $A$ to equal to $|B|$.

I tried
$$
f(x) = A^2  - B^2;\\
f(tx+(1-t)y) - tf(x) - (1-t)f(y);
$$
It seems with the fact that $A = |B|$, the $f(tx+(1-t)y) - tf(x) - (1-t)f(y) \ge 0$, which indicates $f(x)$ is convex.

Is the constraint is really convex?

Cheers,

Dylan

Comment: This question is difficult to read. Please use Tex markup instead of plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint is not convex: the pairs of values for $(A,B)$ given by $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ satisfy the constraint $|A|=B$, but the pair half-way between them not: $(1,0)$.

Only linear equations give rise to convex sets.

Comment: Your last sentence is not technically true (consider $\lfloor x^2+y^2\rfloor=0$), but it's true enough for practical purposes. :)

Comment: Thank you daw. It is so obvious when someone tell the answer :)